# Como criar war para deploy no tomcat com Spring-Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

Estou criando um projeto em Spring-Boot e quero criar o arquivo.war para deploy no Tomcat e não estou conseguindo fazer isso. Estou seguindo este [exemplo](https://receitasdecodigo.com.br/spring-boot/converter-spring-boot-para-arquivo-war) mas ainda não tive sucesso o war não está sendo gerado.

Como fazer isso ?

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>        
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.iguana</groupId>
    <artifactId>CooperativaWS</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>CooperativaWS</name>
    <description>Cooperativa Web Service</description>


    <properties>        
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.iguana.CooperativaWsApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency><!-- basic authentication -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- md5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>          
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tomcat -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>    
                    <mainClass>com.iguana.CooperativaWsApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**SpringBootApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CooperativaWsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CooperativaWsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(CooperativaWsApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está executando o comando para gerar a build? Para fazer isso se você está usando Spring Tool Suite (STS) ou Eclipse você deve clicar com o botão direito no projeto escolher "Run as" -> "Maven build.." e colocar em "Goals": clean package e executar. Se você tem o maven instalado e quiser gerar a build por fora do Spring Tool Suite (STS) ou Eclipse navegue pelo terminal até o diretório do seu projeto então digite: mvn clean package. De acordo com o exemplo você fez tudo corretamente. Você também pode seguir este outro [exemplo](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy).