# Problema em subir aplicação springboot com o tomcat

Tags: java

Boa tarde a todos

Construí uma pequena aplicação spring apenas para fins de aprendizado e estou tentando executa-la com o tomcat, já tentei de tudo e sempre recebo o erro 404. Alguém saberia me explicar qual o problema?

```
package com.fred.springboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(SpringbootApplication.class);
    }

}
```

```
package com.fred.springboot.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController("/")
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping
    public String helloMsg() {
        return "WAR: Hello java spring-boot!!!";
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.fred</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa agora corrigir a dependência `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` do tomcat:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Na tag  você pode melhorar:

```
<build>
    <finalName>Hello</finalName>

    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
            defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
        <plugins>
            <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Depois você roda o build com o botão direito do mouse no projeto em `run as > maven clean` e depois `run as > maven build ...` . O pacote .war vai ser gerado no target. É só copiar e colar no webapp do tomcat (lembrando sempre de limpar o work).

Não deu para ver, mas acredito que o seu index.html esteja na pasta /src/main/resources/templates. Se não estiver, é só criar o caminho e colocar lá.

Basicamente, é só isso mesmo. Minha aplicação está rodando assim no tomcat 9. Se tiver mais alguma dúvida, comenta esse post de resposta.

Links de apoio:

- [Como criar war para deploy no tomcat com Spring-Boot?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/376745/como-criar-war-para-deploy-no-tomcat-com-spring-boot)
- https://receitasdecodigo.com.br/spring-boot/converter-spring-boot-para-arquivo-war